# Setting number of Gibbs steps for BernoulliRBM

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to use `BernoulliRBM` implementation in `scikit-learn` for Restricted Boltzmann Machines, but I can’t find anywhere a way or a parameter to set the number of Gibbs steps k for the PCD sampling. Should I assume that `k=1` and can't be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the training algorithm uses a hardwired "*k*". It can be seen in the [`_fit` method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e341ab47c8ef0a8914795d7ecfbcfaac387f58d/sklearn/neural_network/rbm.py#L249), which samples once, then updates the parameters.